# Sort and display headlines from multiple categories

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this in my page template to display the 20 recent posts headlines from category number 8, 17, 23, 423

```
<div id="horizontalTab">
   <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
     <li>Football</li>
     <li>Ice Hockey</li>
     <li>Basketball</li>
     <li>Tennis</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="resp-tabs-container">
      <?php 
      foreach (get_categories(array('include'=>'8, 17, 23, 423', 'orderby' => 'count', 'order' => DESC)) as $category) {
      $catid = $category->cat_ID;
      $args = array( 'category' =>$catid, 'numberposts' => 20 );
      $myposts = get_posts($args); ?>
      <div>
       <?php foreach($myposts as $post) { ?>
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br/>
       <?php } ?>
     </div>
     <?php } ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

But this code adds more than 10 database queries. How can I optimize this query.
And another question. How can I change the sorting categories in this order: 23, 17, 8, 423.

[See in action](http://www.new.goalstube.ru/)

Answer (score 0):

Why to use get_categories when you already know the categories.
All you have to do is store category IDs in an array and run a loop

```
$cat_array=array(23,17,8,423);
foreach ($cat_array as $catid)
{
$args = array( 'category' =>$catid, 'numberposts' => 20 );
$myposts = get_posts($args); 

  <div>
   <?php foreach($myposts as $post) { ?>
   <a href="<?php $post->guid; ?>"><?php $post->post_title; ?></a><br/>
   <?php } ?>
 </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/h54892/data/www/new.goalstube.ru/wp-content/themes/sandbox/index.php on line 15 (Line 15: $cat_array={23,17,8,423};)

Comment: Without this code page makes 26 db queries and with it 46. Is it possible to optimize?